# libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile occurs when i m training neural network

Tags: conv-neural-network, yolov7

I am training a neural network for custom dataset which has ~7000 images with official yolov7 , while training the model using

```
!python train.py --workers 1 --device 0 --batch-size 4 --epochs 100 --img 640 --data data/custom.yaml --hyp data/hyp.scratch.p5.yaml --cfg cfg/training/yolov7-custom.yaml --name yolov7-custom --weights yolov7.pt
```

the problem is that it I have no idea if its training properly or not and  there are many warnings like these
[it shows at the last of execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIJsZ.png)
[I have no idea what this is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWnQ1.png)
[even no of epochs out of total are not increasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYS6L.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yID61.png)

I expected the line of code to run smoothly and train the model with official yolov7 but nothing happened

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)